# Aligning 2 buttons. 1 left and 1 right

Tags: css

I currently have a VIEW button to the right of this layout but want to add another ADD button to the right.

You can see an example of this on https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/store_v8/shopdisplayproducts.asp?id=5&cat=Barrages+%2F+Cakes+-+Single and then select the GRID VIEW icon

```
<div class="desktop_view product-view grid-list-row-view hide" style="">

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">

    <div class="featured-prod-widget">

      <div class="nailthumb">

        [formatimage sub]
            [CC_ADD_NEW_FLAG]

      </div>

      <div class="row product-details">

        <div class="col-sm-12">

          <h6 class="widget-product-title">[translate cname]</h6>

        </div>

        <div class="row"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-12">

$         <span class="widget-prod-price">[FORMATCUSTOMERPRICE cprice]</span>

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12">



        </div>

      </div>




      **<a href="[formatshopexdlink][add_websesslink]" class="submitbtn pull-left">

        &nbsp;VIEW&nbsp;

      </a>**

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You have used `pull-left` and how can you say it is on right side?? just use same type of HTML & CSS markup for new button with `pull-left` or `pull-right` (as per your need). `pull-left` will take your button on left side and `pull-right` will take button on right side.

Comment: I see what you mean.... If I remove the absolute positioning then the button falls out of the box. What do you suggest to over come this?

Comment: I think removing absolute will not affect anything. just use `pull-left` or `pull-right` as per your need. for example : `<div>
<a href="shopexd.asp?id=524" class="submitbtn" style="float:right">DEMO</a>
<a href="shopexd.asp?id=524" class="submitbtn" style="float:left">VIEW</a>
</div>`. if this doesn't work, then you need to see what other style affecting using developer toolbar.

Comment: I've tried what you said but the images are sitting over the border of the box. You an see an example here. (You will need to click on grid view)

https://www.fireworkscrazy.co.uk/store_v8/shopdisplayproducts.asp?id=5&cat=Barrages+%2F+Cakes+-+Single

Comment: Where the buttons are positioned seems to be tied to the size or more specifically the height of the product image.

Answer (score 0):

the style `.grid-list-row-view .featured-prod-widget .submitbtn` affecting your button. it has absolute position. so with same style if you create button with `pull-left` or `pull-right` , it will display on same position instead of left or right. 
 you will need to implement some workaround to overcome or remove `absolute` style.